# Dapr time out issue while connecting to Azure Redis from local

Tags: azure, .net-core, redis, dapr, dapr-sidekick

I have Dapr sample Counter application which working fine with local redis server, but if I try to connect with "Azure redis for cache" I am getting time out error.

My yaml file with sample azure redis connection string

[image]

Time out error

[image]

Need suggestion on the yaml file either I have configured properly or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your YAML file, the problem appears to be the metadata value, which **should be localhost and port 6379**. This was a time-out issue; ensure that relay ports are enabled.

```
 metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
```

**NOTE:**
In this self-hosted mode, verify whether the component files are automatically created or not.

```
  **Windows**:  `%USERPROFILE%\.dapr\components\`
  **Linux/MacOS**:  `$HOME/.dapr/components`
```

refer below [tutorial](https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/tutorials/configure-state-pubsub/) for more details.

Comment: Hi, if I use "value: localhost:6379" its working fine, problem is happening only when try to connect to the Azure redis cache using the connecting string. Can you provide some YAML sample with connecting to Azure.

Comment: Find the same connection string under Kubernetes tab on above Tutorial.      
 metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: <REPLACE WITH HOSTNAME redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local:6379>
  - name: redisPassword

Comment: @Swarana Thanks for the details, problem is I have used the azure redis password directly in the place of "secretKeyRef", instead of using it in "redisPassword" with value also enableTLS flag need to be set when using the azure. EX: `apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: statestore
spec:
  type: state.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: Azurehost.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
  - name: redisPassword
    value: <Azure password>
  - name: enableTLS
    value: true `